# Start marquee after touch event in android

Tags: android, android-layout, marquee

I have one Linear Layout which contains three List Views and Three Buttons. I have customized the List View elements. I just want that if anyone touches the element of a List View then the corresponding text view should give effect as a marquee.

The main Linear Layout is as below -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:textSize="16dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/more_button1"
    android:layout_width="130dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="More" >
</Button>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:textSize="16dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/more_button2"
    android:layout_width="130dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="More" >
</Button>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:textSize="16dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/more_button3"
    android:layout_width="130dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:text="More" >
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Customized List Items are as below (list_item_1, list_item_2, list_item_3)-

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:freezesText="true"
android:lines="1"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:padding="10dp"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
android:singleLine="true"
android:textSize="20sp" >

</TextView>
```

And the activity is as below -

```
public class MarqueeActivity extends Activity {

ListView lv1 = null;
ListView lv2 = null;
ListView lv3 = null;

String s1[] = {"Hello This is a long Text which will help in tsting", "How", "Are", "You"};
String s2[] = {"I", "Am", "Fine"};
String s3[] = {"Welcome", "In", "New", "World"};    

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
    lv3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list3);

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_1, s1));
    lv2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_2, s2));
    lv3.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_3, s3));

    }
}
```

For e.g. If the activity is started and then someone touches the first element in first list view (Hello This is a long Text which will help in testing) then it should start marquee.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

This works :

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Child at 0 pos"," "+lv1.getChildAt(pos));
            txtv = (TextView)lv1.getChildAt(pos);
            txtv.setSelected(true);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Infact **txtv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);** is not required. Just txtv.setSelected(true) will do the work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but the colour of text is getting changed after touch event (May be its a property). Again the application is crashing if we click on last item (You) in lv1 (txtv is getting null value) and if we click on second last element (Are) then the last item is getting selected.

Comment: Its working for me. Please post your code. Also please upvote my answer if the solution works for you.

Comment: lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
     long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv = (TextView) lv1.getChildAt(position);
    tv.setSelected(true);
    tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(2);
   }
  });

Comment: The code which you posted also works fine! I printed the TextView objects in Log and i cud get all the four.

Comment: The problem arises when we click on the 4th element, application gets crash.

Answer (score 0):

You can runtime set `android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"` for textview on  Touch event

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that? I implemented one onItemClickListener to the list view(say lv1) with method onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long id) {}. Now I know which element has been clicked, but how to start marquee on that particular element? (I suppose I need to use the method setMarqueeRepeatLimit() on an element).

Comment: I tried setting that parameter but not working. I think something else also should be used along with that.